# Why doesn't getConfiguraton().locale match locale.US?

Tags: android

When my app starts up for the first time, I want to detect the user's current locale and set a SharedPreference accordingly. I'm grabbing the user's current locale from getResources(), which I've come to understand is set when the app starts for the first time:

```
// Set the locale
Locale locale = getResources().getConfiguration().locale;
if(locale != Locale.US)
{
    Log.i("ActivityDownloader", "Locale: " + locale.toString() + ", (" + Locale.US.toString() + ")");
}
```

Unfortunately, I'm seeing that log entry in the console with the following text:

> I/ActivityDownloader: Locale: en_US, (en_US)

Why don't the two Locale match? Should I be matching Locale.toString() instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `equals()` method. The `==` and `!=` operators won't work for this.

```
Locale locale = getResources().getConfiguration().locale;
if(!locale.equals(Locale.US))
{
    Log.i("ActivityDownloader", "Locale: " + locale.toString() + ", (" + Locale.US.toString() + ")");
}
```

I believe this is because `==` and `!=` will compare references rather than the value. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/767379/935779